# Mariadb losses data after system is restarted

Tags: wordpress, docker, mariadb

Using the following docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '2'

services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: my_db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: root
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html

  mysql:
    image: mariadb
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
```

I ran the command `docker-compose up`, installed WP and then added few posts to WP. but after restarting my system everything losses and I again need to fix the db. How can I preserve the db, like I have saved my code in ./src folder?

Comment: See the `-v` option in `docker` for mounting 'permanent' files outside the instance.

Answer (score 1):

Configure database directory to be on a volume so that db can be preserved.

Refer `Where to Store Data` section on the page https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mount the volume somewhere on ur local disk.

Try adding this to ur mariadb container

```
mysql:
    image: mariadb
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
        - your/local/path:/var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: Now getting error  [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace, looks like its bcoz of permission issue for your/local/path folder

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40971034/unable-to-run-mariadb-when-mount-volume